# rotation of the element does not fit in place

Tags: css, user-interface, frontend, web-frontend

i tried to rotate the elements with different widths but the result is 2 elements are not in place after being rotated and stacked on each other, i tried to change the css position of the elements after being rotated according to their place but still stacked

[image: output picture]

```css
.drop{
      border: 1px solid gray;
      width:50px;
      height:200px;
      margin:50px;
    }
.drop div{
      transform:rotate(90deg);
      margin:0 auto;
  padding:0 auto;
    }


// i try this but not right
 
    /* .drop div.box1 {
            transform: rotate(270deg);
            position: relative;
        }
    
    .drop div.box2 {
            transform: rotate(-90deg) translate(-100%);
            transform-origin: top left;
            display: block;
            position: relative;
        }
    
     .drop div.box3 {
            transform: rotate(-90deg) translate(-100%);
            transform-origin: top left;
            display: block;
            position: relative;
        } */
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="drop">
      <div class="box1 bg-warning" style="width:50px;height:50px;"></div>
      <div class="box2 bg-dark" style="width:75px;height:50px"></div>
      <div class="box3 bg-danger" style="width:100px;height:50px"></div></div>
```

[image]

desired the result, even though the placement of the elements is changed, the display remains neat

Comment: Please add the relevant code to your question, and not on an external website.

Comment: A proper [mre] of your issue belongs directly into your question, not just dumped onto an external platform. Please edit your question accordingly.

Comment: By default, the elements get rotated around their own center, because that is the default value for [`transform-origin`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transform-origin).

Comment: hi @GreyRoofPigeon
thanks for your response, I have changed the code in code snipet

Comment: hi @CBroe
thanks for your response, I've tried to set the css with transform origin, the result is in the border that has been provided but the elements are stacked on top of each other

Answer (score 0):

This is because the div elements are rotated from the center by default. This behavior can be modified with [transform-origin](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/t/transform-origin/)

In your case you want to rotate them from the top left corner with `transform-origin: left bottom`

```css
.drop{
      border: 1px solid gray;
      width:50px;
      height:200px;
      margin:50px;
    }
.drop div{
      transform:rotate(90deg);
      transform-origin: left bottom;
      margin:0 auto;
      padding:0 auto;
    }
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="drop">
      <div class="box1 bg-warning" style="width:50px;height:50px;"></div>
      <div class="box2 bg-dark" style="width:75px;height:50px"></div>
      <div class="box3 bg-danger" style="width:100px;height:50px"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: hi @Remco Kersten 
thanks for your response, but what you made is already inside the border but still piling up each other